# What is the maximum radius of $k$ spheres that fit inside a sphere of radius $r$?

Tags: spheres, packing-problem

I came across this problem the other day and couldn't figure out a way to solve it easily or any clear answer when searching in literature.

Taking a sphere of radius $r$ in a 3 dimensional Euclidian space and taking an arbitrary number $ k \in \mathbb{N}$ of identical  hard (non overlapping) spheres, is there an existing known value for their maximum radius as a function of $k$ and $r$ such that they all fit inside the first sphere?

I am here letting aside any consideration of optimal configuration and just looking for a general answer which remains true in average with random configurations. However if you only had an answer taking into account such considerations, I'd be happy any way!
This problem is really close to the [Sphere packing in sphere problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_packing_in_a_sphere) or to the [kissing number considerations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kissing_number) but even knowing that I wasn't able to find a clear answer, since I don't have access to the main reference of the wikipedia page (Les Cahiers du LMPA J. Liouville, 2003).

If you have any idea of the general form of the answer or any litterature advice on the subject I would really be grateful!

Thanks.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_packing_in_a_sphere) can be manipulated into your desired answer.

Comment: Yes but I was hopping that a general answer was existing, which would have avoided me to have to play with different multiples. Plus if I am interating one of these situations (for example having k=16 spheres using the 4th described described on this page) I can't be sure that this radius is still the maximum since the configuration changed (one could for examples rearrange the spheres so the gap are more filled since the spheres are smaller).

Comment: There's no general solution. You find the radius that you have, and pick the radius just bigger than the one you have on the list.

Comment: Is there a paper somewhere that you would know about, on the subject of the abscence of general solutions? Or is it just commonly known? Thanks a lot for your help anyway.